# leaflet .bindLabel using geojson feature

Tags: leaflet

I am new to leaflet and I'd like to add labels to my point map features derived from geojson format.

I am getting the error: TypeError: layer.bindLabel is not a function in this script https://jsfiddle.net/gfiske/ksx600sn/35/  (uncomment line 129)

Can anyone suggest a workaround or a better approach?

thanks.

```
geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {


style: function(feature) {
    return {
      color: feature.properties.GPSUserColor
    };
  },
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 7,
      fillOpacity: 0.75
    });
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.MAP_LABEL);
    layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.MAP_LABEL);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation for [`Leaflet.label`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label#leafletlabel):

> NOTE: starting with Leaflet 1.0, L.Label is added to Leaflet core as L.Tooltip and this plugin is deprecrated.

You should use [`bindTooltip`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#tooltip) instead:

```js
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.MAP_LABEL);
  layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.MAP_LABEL);
}
```